# Difference between import matplotlib and import matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I imported matplotlib by using only `import matplotlib`, whether the pyplot was imported or not.

Following is a code to show my problem :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt
print(np.sin(180))
x_sin=np.arange(0, 3*3.14 ,0.1)
print(x_sin)
y_sin=np.sin(x_sin)
print(y_sin)
plt.pyplot.plot(x_sin,y_sin)
```

When I tried to run this code it gave me the error:

> AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'pyplot'

Comment: `matplotlib` and `matplotlib.pyplot` are different modules, simple as that. Note that `matplotlib.pyplot` is a single dotted name, and not an attribute lookup on the `matplotlib` module.

Comment: @Brian61354270: Well, in the context of an `import` statement, `matplotlib.pyplot` isn't an attribute lookup. If you try to use `matplotlib.pyplot` later in an expression, that'll be an attribute lookup.

Answer (score 2):

You need to be explicit of the module you want to import, in your case is the `pyplot`.

The usual way using of importing `pyplot`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

or

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
print(np.sin(180))
x_sin = np.arange(0, 3*3.14, 0.1)
print(x_sin)
y_sin = np.sin(x_sin)
print(y_sin)
plt.plot(x_sin, y_sin)
```